# Why does HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath return an empty string?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

When user requests `http://localhost/WebApp1/Default.aspx`, `txtApplicationPath.Text` should be assigned `“/WebApp1”`, while `txtAbsolutePath.Text` should be assigned  `“http://localhost/WebApp1/Default.aspx”`, but instead both textboxes display empty strings.

Why?

Default.aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtApplicationPath" runat="server" 
    Text='<%# HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath %>'>
</asp:TextBox> <br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAbsolutePath" runat="server" 
    Text='<%# HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath %>'>
</asp:TextBox>
```

thank you

Comment: I had the same result. It'll work if you populate those TextBoxes in code-behind instead of markup.

Comment: Ups, reason it didn't work is because I forgot to call Page.Databind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want the full url you should use Request.Url.OriginalString, because AbsolutePath will omit the host part of the url.