# ASP.NET webforms negation expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

Cant I use negation on asp.net web froms expression on a page?

That's what I have:

```
 ... Visible='<%# Presenter.CanEdit>' ...
```

That's what I need:

```
 ... Visible='<%# !Presenter.CanEdit>' ...
```

Comment: .. have you tried it ?

Comment: Is this in a repeater? Either way, IMO it's easier/cleaner to do in the code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to cast it to a bool first

```
... Visible='<%# !(bool)Presenter.CanEdit>' ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Page.DataBind()` and then it will work, even if the control is not a typical `DataBound` control.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6836687/546000