# Passing variables to javascript in repeater imagebutton onclientclick

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to pass my dynamic value to a javascript function from an imagebutton onclientclick event.
It works fine if I pass the static value like this

```html
<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/control_play_blue.png" ForeColor="Transparent"
                        BorderStyle="None" ToolTip="Chat" runat="server" ID="btnChat" 
                        OnClientClick="javascript:return openWindow('1')" />
```

However it doesn't work if I try to pass dynamic values as below.

```html
<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/control_play_blue.png" ForeColor="Transparent" BorderStyle="None" ToolTip="Chat" runat="server" ID="btnChat" 
                        OnClientClick="javascript:return openWindow('"+<%#Eval("PujaType") %>+"')" />
```

I tried all possible combinations however it says tag is not well formatted.
Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know ASP, but in JSP the expression has to be the entire value. Try:

```
OnClientClick="<%# "javascript:return openWindow('" + Eval("PujaType") + "')" %>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Its been awhile since I have worked with ASP.NET and currently cannot test this, but I seem to recall it requiring single quotes when wrapping the `<%# %>`.

Something like this:

```
<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/control_play_blue.png" ForeColor="Transparent"
                        BorderStyle="None" ToolTip="Chat" runat="server" ID="btnChat" 
                        OnClientClick='<%# "javascript:return openWindow('" + Eval("PujaType") + "')" %>' />
```

Some of the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836534/asp-net-textbox-is-it-possible-to-initialize-text-attribute-with-in-line-code) suggest the same.

---

An alternative would be setting the value in the code behind. Assuming you are using this control inside a repeator or something similar, you should be able to set the value during data binding like this:

```
void R1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {

  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {

     String pujaType = ((YourType)e.Item.DataItem).PujaType;

     ((ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("btnChat")).OnClientClick = "javascript:return openWindow('" + pujaType + "')";
  }
}
```

[Repeater.ItemDataBound Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

---

Another alternative, since you are not making use of any serverside events, would be to use regular html instead of an ASP.NET control. This could be done with an anchor and img tag like so:

```
<a href="#" onclick="openWindow('<%# Eval("pujaType") %>'); return false;">
  <img src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Images/control_play_blue.png") %>' />
</a>
```

Comment: @user2969030 - see alternatives

Answer (score 0):

You don't need string concatenation around your `Eval` statement.  Doing so is creating invalid markup.

Change

`"javascript:return openWindow('"+<%#Eval("PujaType") %>+"')"`

to

`"javascript:return openWindow('<%#Eval("PujaType") %>')"`

```
<asp:ImageButton    
     ImageUrl="~/Images/control_play_blue.png"ForeColor="Transparent"   
     BorderStyle="None" ToolTip="Chat" runat="server" ID="btnChat" 
     OnClientClick="javascript:return openWindow('<%#Eval("PujaType") %>')" />
```